# "ERROR: Problems trying to get index of users!" on moodle-drupal services syncing error on Drupal 7.x + Moodle 2.x

Tags: drupal, moodle

I am using the instructions from https://github.com/cannod/moodle-drupalservices/wiki/Installation-Drupal-Side to integrate my Drupal sign-in with a Moodle installation. I have successfully completed the steps and ran the "tests" indicating that my Drupal service is set up correctly. I.e., I am able to log in to Drupal using the "remote" user and get a valid JSON response from the service endpoint. However, after completing the "Moodle side" instructions, I tried to manually run the database sync file from the command line as per the instructions and received the following output:

```
RemoteAPI Object
(
    [gateway] => mysitesurl.com
    [endpoint] => /drupalservice
    [status] => 1
    [session] => SESScc2ded1dd0a5... //this part is okay
    [sessid] => vtlmSjtBINVA... //this part is okay as well
)
ERROR: Problems trying to get index of users!
```

I looked at the code, and the [status] of 1 seems to indicate that the log in was successful, so I can't imagine what the issue is. I found a couple of other people on this site saying they had the same problem, then replied to their own post with something along the lines of "I figured it out!" and not posting the answer.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of wanting to pull my hair out, I figured it out. Something VERY helpful to know for troubleshooting is that within the function CurlHttpRequest (line 135), you can access any curl errors generated while accessing your service. I just echoed that out and discovered that the request was timing out before the results were delivered, so I went into the GetCurlGet function and upped CURLOPT_TIMEOUT a little and, walla! Everything worked great after that.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create view properly that's why u got error, follow the instruction carefully, I did and it's working perfect from my side.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue. I followed your suggestion and combed over my view a couple of times, then re-built it from scratch. I did the same with the service. Still get the same error. Here is the sample from what is produced for the service: 
`[{"name":"admin","uid":"1","firstname":"First","lastname":"Last","city":"Somecity","country":"US","email":"email@noaddress.com","status":"1"}]`